# Flex 4.5 TabNavigator cornerRadius not working

Tags: apache-flex, tabnavigator, cornerradius

I'm having the hardest time finding a way to simply add rounded tabs to a TabNavigator control.

I have seen examples which seem to be really simple but they don't seem to work in Flex 4.5.  Here is some sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"     minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Style source="style.css"/>

<mx:TabNavigator x="93" y="90" width="571" height="293" tabStyleName="tabstyle">
    <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Tab 1">
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:TabNavigator>
</s:Application>
```

and the css:

```
/* CSS file */
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

.tabstyle
{
corner-radius: 10;
}
```

I have also tried cornerRadius: 10;

Any ideas why this does not work?  Any easy to follow solution (I'm a beginner).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a skin for your app/tab navigator, use the 'create copy of' option in Flash Builder, and in the Rect section, set the radiusX, radiusY values. Then use that skin for the component

Comment: Sorry I'm really not very experienced here.  I have created skin copies for Spark components before but I have not had any luck creating a skin copy for a mx control.  Could you walk me through the steps to create the skin copy and then apply it to the mx:TabNavigator control?

Comment: It cant be done for mx controls, sorry. This is a perfect workaround: http://devgirl.org/2009/11/16/tabbed-navigation-in-flex-4/

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and easiest workaround I know for this problem. It seems Adobe never solved this bug.

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="0" >
    <s:Group width="100%">
        <s:TabBar left="4" dataProvider="{tabNav}" cornerRadius="4" />
    </s:Group>
    <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%" cornerRadius="4">
        <mx:ViewStack id="tabNav" paddingBottom="10" width="100%" height="100%" >
            <s:NavigatorContent label="Form" width="100%" height="100%">
                ...
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <mx:Canvas id="treeNode" label="TreeNodeComponent" width="100%" height="100%">
                ...
            </mx:Canvas>
            <mx:Canvas id="melding" label="Melding" width="100%" height="100%" visible="{authorisation.moduleHasUserAutorization('melding')}" includeInLayout="{melding.visible}">
                ...
            </mx:Canvas>
        </mx:ViewStack>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:VGroup>
```

It's the equivalent of this but with rounded corners in the tabs (and body):

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="tabNav" paddingBottom="10" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Form" width="100%" height="100%">
        ...
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <mx:Canvas id="treeNode" label="TreeNodeComponent" width="100%" height="100%">
        ...
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas id="melding" label="Melding" width="100%" height="100%" visible="{authorisation.moduleHasUserAutorization('melding')}" includeInLayout="{melding.visible}">
        ...
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="tabNavigator" tabOffset="20" cornerRadius="10" height="100%" width="100%">
```

Comment: I'v tried the cornerRadius but it only sets a radius on the content area not the tabs.

Comment: The problem is about the rounding of the tabs, not it's content.

Answer (score -1):

This is the sample code you can copy and run

```
        <s:NavigatorContent id="search" label="Search"  width="100%" height="100%" fontWeight="bold" 
                            >

            <s:layout>

                <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"  
                                  paddingTop="5" paddingLeft="5" 
                                  paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="5" />
            </s:layout>

            <s:Label text="Search Panel" />
            <s:HGroup >
                <s:TextInput id="Searchtxt" width="200" />
                <mx:Button label="search" click="Searchtxt.text=''" />
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:NavigatorContent>

        <s:NavigatorContent id="custInfo" label="Customer Info" backgroundColor="0xDCDCDC" 
                            width="100%" height="100%" fontWeight="bold" >

            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"  
                                  paddingTop="5" paddingLeft="5" 
                                  paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="5" />
            </s:layout>

            <s:Label text="Customer Info" />
            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Label text="Email Address"/>
                <s:TextInput id="email" width="200"/>
                <s:Button label="Submit" click="email.text='';" />
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:NavigatorContent>

        <s:NavigatorContent id="accountInfo" label="Account Info" backgroundColor="0xDCDCDC" width="100%" height="100%" fontWeight="bold" >

            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"  
                                  paddingTop="5" paddingLeft="5" 
                                  paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="5" />
            </s:layout>

            <s:Label text="Account Info" />
            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Button label="Purchases" />
                <s:Button label="Sales" />
                <s:Button label="Reports" />
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:NavigatorContent>

    </mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: This answer is also off topic. This even doesn't have tabs... The corner radius of tab's of an mx TabNavigator in Flex 4.5, that's the problem.